# Is function has exactly one real root? If a function is injective, continuous and differentiable everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions

If a function is injective, continuous, and differentiable everywhere. Can we directly say the function has exactly one root? It seems function has exactly one root If a function is injective, continuous, and differentiable everywhere.
I think It's the intermediate value theorem.
But I think this injective graph hasn't a root?[image]

when the graph goes minus infinity actually can we say the gradient is zero???
I haven't the tough idea If a function is injective, continuous, and differentiable everywhere, It has exactly real root.
Can you offer some assistance to clarify this mess.
Sorry for the poor English language manipulation
Thank you!

Comment: Polynomial have roots. General functions have, or not, *zeros" (or "zeroes") . And no, the function can be bijective (wrt some sets) and still the function may not have zero gradient = derivative equal to zero, at all.. An example is a function that ressembles the one  depicted in your question: $\;f(x)=e^x\;$ is a function $\;\Bbb R\to (0,\infty)\;$ which is bijective but its defivative is $\;e^x>0\;$ always.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that these conditions don't guarantee a real root.  An easy example is $y=e^x$, which is injective, continuous, and differentiable everywhere, but has no real roots.  Of course, any injective function can only have at most $1$ real root.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=1+e^x$ is injective, continuous, and differentiable everywhere, yet it has no roots.